# Wordpress not detecting content-aside.php and similar

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress and I have hit a very frustrating block.
I am trying to set up post formats, which I have done, and can select from the admin panel, but none of them will recognise my content-(whatever).php file. The code below resembles the files that I am using. It is worth noting that I have tested to see that the format is being detected (I used an echo) and it works.

I have no idea where I am going wrong and any help would be hugely appreciated.

**page-blog.php**

```
<?php include('header_content.php'); ?>
<div class="top_spacer"></div>
<div id="main_cont">
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : 
    the_post(); 

get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

    endwhile;   

    else :
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';
endif;
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**content-aside.php**

```
hi there, this is a test
```

**functions.php**

```
    <?php
//Blog support and other
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3 );function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {  $html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';  return $html;}

// Add Post format support
add_theme_support('post-formats' , array('status' , 'aside' , 'link' , 'gallery')) ;

//Navigation Menu
register_nav_menus(array(
'primary' => __ ('Primary Menu')
));
```

**content.php**

```
<article class="post">
  <?php
    $args = array( 'category' => 2, 'post_type' =>  'post' ); 
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );    
    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
    ?>  
    <div class="post_cont"> <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail();} ?>   <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p class="post_info"><?php the_time('F jS, Y G:i'); ?></p>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </div>  
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </article>
```

Comment: What output are you getting by above code?

Comment: Hi Nilambar, the code above seems to totally ignore 'content-whatever.php' and default back to content.php. If i force it to load content-aside.php, it works for aside posts, but the get_post_format just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I tested your above code and it is working fine.

Comment: Can you `var_dump` value of `get_post_format` and check what it is returning?

Comment: I was echoing out the value on the end of a string. So that title was 'This is a ' .get_post_format()  . That was returning the correct format for the post.

Comment: Can you please explain how you have used `page-blog.php`? It is not Page template I believe.

Comment: the -blog is just the slug of my blog page so that it will load a separate layout for that page compared to others. Do you think that could be the issue?

Comment: I am not sure but you should definitely check by renaming to other page name.  Say `page-articles.php`. And create page with title `Articles`.

Comment: I renamed it to page.php just to be in the safe side but it hasn't made a difference to the format issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. You have used `page-blog.php` here. When WordPress select this template, main query will of a single page, `Blog` here. So `get_post_format` in your code wont fetch correct value as `Blog` has not any post format.

**Alternative approach:**

If you want to have separate design for your blog posts then you can use `home.php`. Go to `Settings` -> `Reading`. Choose your `Blog` page for `Posts Page` option. Then you will get correct listing of posts.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nilambar but I am afraid that it has not fixed the issue.